# Access Violation when assign new value to char* variable

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm testing this following code, but when is executed comes a AV in this line:

```
*port = 0;
```

how solve this? what i'm making wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *host = "127.0.0.1:1234";
    char *port = strchr(host, ':');

    if (port)
    {
        *port = 0;
        ++port;
        printf("%s \n", *port);

        int portInt = strtol(port, NULL, 10);

        printf("%d: \n", portInt);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You also don't need all of that code to duplicate the error.  It is undefined behavior to modify a string literal. i.e. `int main() { char *p = "abc"; p[0] = 'x'; }` -- same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're attempting to modify a string literal (`host`).  String literals are `const`, thus attempting to modify one is undefined behavior.

Since `port` points to one of the characters in the string literal, attempting to modify that value by doing this:

`*port = 0;`

results in undefined behavior, in your case, a crash.

One fix is to simply make `host` an array of `char`:

```
char host[] = "127.0.0.1:1234";
char *port = strchr(host, ':');
```

Since the declaration has been changed to an array for `host`, all the characters within that array become modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *port = strchr(host, ':');
```

produces a pointer to ':' **in** the host string, and since you defined a literal string

```
char *host = "127.0.0.1:1234";`
```

`host` is a pointer to a read-only memory location and thus

```
*port = 0;
```

actually tries to write into the read-only `host` string.

you could write:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  // define a const as const
  const char *host_default = "127.0.0.1:1234";

  // dup host if you want to write in it, or change.
  char *host=strdup(host_default);

  if (!host) exit(-1); // check if memory was allocated!

  // port pointer to `:` in memory of host String
  char *port = strchr(host, ':');

  if (port)
  {
    *port = 0; // have host to be Null terminated
    ++port;
    printf("%s \n", port);

    long portInt = strtol(port, NULL, 10);

    printf("Port: %ld: \n", portInt);
    // I can only assume you also want the hostname, seen the *port = 0;
    printf("HostName: %s: \n", host);
  }
  // free allocated memory;
  free(host);
  // set to NULL, good practise
  host=NULL;
  // set port also to NULL as it might point to released memory of host
  port=NULL;

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```